# Keyboard not working on kodi, rpi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, kodi, keyboard

I have a rpi2 with raspbian installed and a remote wireless keyboard with an attached mouse touchpad. The keyboard works normally on the OS (browser, terminal etc) but not in kodi. There I can use the mouse touchpad, the keyboard arrows and the enter button but when the virtual keyboard is displayed (on search, for example) it won't recognize letter keystrokes as such so I have to fall back and select letter by letter either with the mouse pointer or with the arrows.

Under System/Input Devices/Peripheral I can see CEC adapter but no keyboard.
I updated kodi config to start with pi user and edited sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-permissions.rules as suggested in [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27077/kodi-xbmc-on-raspbian-cant-activate-keyboard-or-mouse).

**System info:**
Raspbian 7, kernel 4.1.13-v7+
Kodi 14.2

Comment: Welcome to RPi.SE. Did you try the last answer in that thread ? It sounds promising and the easiest out of all 3. I'm sure that you must have rebooted after all the changes that you made but confirming it anyway. Did you reboot ?

Comment: I had not rebooted, seems to work now even after I reverted the start user, thanks!

Comment: Hello; what do you mean by "revert the start user?"

Comment: In the linked thread it says to "Change user from kodi to pi in /etc/default/kodi file." I reverted it back to kodi

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, just noticed that running kodi from the command line (logged in with the pi user) the keyboard works fine. The problem shows only when kodi is started at boot (with user pi). 
I think it's something related to the user login in a terminal vs. starting kodi process in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a toggle option in kodi on how to accept key strokes. I can't remember what it's called but you could give it a try?  It's called something like 'treat keyboard input as input.. '