# Kodi won't start as "kodi" user

Tags: kodi

On a fresh rasbian, I've installed kodi from the package manager. I had trouble with making kodi run at startup and after some tests I came to the conclusion than **kodi won't start if run as the kodi user**.

When run as the "pi" user (`USER=pi` in `/etc/default/kodi`), `service kodi start` does the job and I get a responding kodi interface. When run as the "kodi" user (`USER=kodi` in `/etc/default/kodi`), `service kodi start` does start kodi but it **immediatly hangs: the webserver does not respond, keyboard commands do nothing**...

The directory `/home/kodi/.kodi/` does exist and contains the expected file hierarchy (`addons/ media/  sounds/  system/  temp/  userdata/`)

---

**Note**: This question is indeed a duplicate, and [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27104/37231) solved my problem. But I wouldn't suggest to delete this question as it describes the issue more precisely I think and it will help others to find the linked solution.