# Raspbian, Kodi uses keyboard as a remote, not to type

Tags: usb, kodi, keyboard

I just installed Kodi on my Raspberry Pi 3 via Raspbian, so I don't have to switch SD Cards when I need to watch a YouTube video and then return to the desktop.

A problem I encountered is that my keyboard is not working properly. When I enter a search or a text field in Kodi, a virtual keyboard pops up, and I am unable to type using my physical keyboard.

The display is not a touchscreen, it is just a regular TV.

While, keys such as *C* open *context menu*, for example, arrows, ESC, Return and every shortcut key work, I am not able to use the keyboard as a typing device. I already tried to follow these guides and Stack Exchange answers:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=99866
- [kodi (xbmc) on raspbian can't activate keyboard or mouse](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27077/kodi-xbmc-on-raspbian-cant-activate-keyboard-or-mouse)

Here's what I did to install Kodi:

```
sudo apt-get update
# to refresh package list, then
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

SD card has just been flashed with newest Raspbian, keyboard is IT attached via USB.

**UPDATE:** I made a few tries and I found out that the num pad is acting as one of those cheap phone keyboards with alphabet letters, just like ones on old Nokia phones, where you press a number more times and you cycle between letters, like:
2 -> a b c 2 A B C
3 -> d e f 3 D E F
And so on, while 1 does special symbols and number 1.

It's bad when a thing doesn't work, but it's even more frustrating when something only works partially.

Comment: Is the display actually a touchscreen?

Comment: No, it's not. It's my TV

Comment: It sounds like your keyboard FN (Function) lock is enabled.... Keyboard is the oldest thing ever. If its a USB keyboard it emulates PS2 - So its very strange why kodi is interpreting the keystrokes in such a strange way.

Comment: I had the same problem when I installed Kodi on a Raspbian Jessie Pi3 in May.. I "solved it" by installing LibreELEC instead - then the keyboard worked properly. Of course, this doesn't solve your problem, but it might help someone else to do so.. :-)

Comment: If I only had to use Kodi, then there would be no reason to run it on Raspbian: I could very well flash SD w/ OSMC then boom. Problem is I also need Desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same keyboard-input problem with Kodi 17 on Raspbian Jessie.

It only went away when I added the following to /etc/rc.local (before the "exit" line):

```
chmod 0777 /dev/tty0
```

I found this solution after reading the instructions at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=99866

It seems a bit of a hacky solution though, and I don't know why it's necessary because Kodi is clearly getting the keyboard input, just ignoring it for the text input fields. Perhaps we should weigh in at the Kodi bugtracker ( http://trac.kodi.tv/ticket/15902 )?

Answer (score 1):

The use of `/etc/rc.local` is deprecated in modern versions of Debian and its derivatives, including Raspbian, which use systemd.  Here is the preferred way to implement the workaround in Raspbian Stretch.  The steps assume that you are working in a root shell (e.g., via `sudo bash`).

1. Ensure that the user running kodi (in my case, `kodi`) is in the `tty` group:

   ```
   # usermod -a -G tty kodi
   ```
2. Create a new service as follows:

   ```
   # cat <<EOF >/lib/systemd/system/kodi-enable-keyboard.service
   [Unit]
   Description = Kodi Keyboard Enabler
   After = remote-fs.target network-online.target
   Wants = network-online.target

   [Service]
   ExecStart = /bin/chmod 0660 /dev/tty0

   [Install]
   WantedBy = multi-user.target
   EOF
   ```
3. Start the new service and tell systemd that you want it started on every boot:

   ```
   # systemctl daemon-reload
   # systemctl start kodi-enable-keyboard.service
   # systemctl enable kodi-enable-keyboard.service
   ```
4. If you are already running Kodi as a systemd service, then you should ensure that it gets started *after* the `kodi-enable-keyboard` service by specifying `After = kodi-enable-keyboard.service` in its `[Unit]` section.  For example, you might want to change your entire `/lib/systemd/system/kodi.service` file to look something like the following:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description = Kodi Media Center
   After = kodi-enable-keyboard.service
   Wants = network-online.target

   [Service]
   User = kodi
   Group = kodi
   Type = simple
   ExecStart = /usr/bin/kodi
   Restart = on-abort
   RestartSec = 5

   [Install]
   WantedBy = multi-user.target
   ```
5. Regardless whether or not you are running Kodi as a service, you need to restart it for the keyboard fix to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Using RPI 3 with Kodi v17

Building on @Paul M's answer, you can add the user running kodi (kodi in my case) to the group tty and then placing the below in `/etc/rc.local`

```
chmod 0660 /dev/tty0
```

This solves it in a similar manner, while avoiding allowing *everyone* to write to `/dev/tty0`

The permissions are generally `620 root:tty`. For some reason, kodi needs the read permission (2 + 4: 620 -> 660) to allow you to type into the search with a keyboard?